# How to make LibreOffice Portable only convert single page to pdf

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf, docx, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am trying to display the first page of a word document in the browser as a thumbnail and to do this I convert the docx to a pdf. However this takes some time to occur since it’s converting the entire document therefore I was trying to speed this up by only converting the first page that will display on the browser. Is this possible rather than converting every page of the docx file?

‘’’

```
    public static void ConvertToPDF(string PathToItemToConvert, string PathToLibrePortable)
{
        bool converted = false;

        try
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(PathToItemToConvert);
            string fileDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(PathToItemToConvert);

            var pdfProcess = new Process();
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.FileName = PathToLibrePortable;
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.Arguments =
                String.Format("--norestore --nofirststartwizard --headless --convert-to pdf  \"{0}\""
                                      , fileName);
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = fileDir;
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pdfProcess.Start();

            string output = pdfProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            converted = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            converted = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Or should I just be converting the docx to html with libreoffice and my entire approach is flawed as I don’t need the saved copy of the pdf as these docx files change often.

Comment: Please see [**this answer**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/headless-writer-pdf-export-filter-options-format/33720/2?u=johnsun) and [**this list of options**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Tutorials/PDF_export#General_properties). I hope this helps solve the single sheet export issue (not sure).

Comment: You might be able to get a line like `" --norestore  --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export:{"PageRange":{"type":"string","value":"1"}}' \"{0}\""` to work, because there is [**a page**](https://git.libreoffice.org/core/+/0c3b8792b712e939d2ad524d554f96616b4844be) that [**this answer**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/solved-convert-to-pdf-with-specific-settings-from-command/40192/4?u=johnsun) pointed to (*I did not succeed*)

Comment: You said you did not succeed. Did you try PageRange and it failed to convert?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant - before commenting, I tried many different command line options and did not succeed: either the output PDF is not created at all, or the entire source document ends up in the output file. Let's hope this gets it right soon. In the meantime, you could change your algorithm: open the document in Writer, set the export options for one page, export, and close the document (using the API). Yes, it's a bit more complicated than the command line conversion, but it should work.

Comment: Not sure but this site indicates to use draw_pdf_export .Not sure how that compares to yours in writer_pdf_export? https://vmiklos.hu/blog/pdf-convert-to.html

Comment: As far as I understand this blog article, Miklos talking about the implementation of the **mechanism for passing parameters** to the filter. Yes, draw_pdf_Export is specified in the examples, but all these filters - writer_pdf_Export, calc_pdf_Export, impress_pdf_Export - use the same set of parameters, which means that if the parameter passing mechanism works for one of them, then it should work for the others too.

Comment: That’s a good point. I guess libreoffice might just be broken. I too couldn’t get this pagerange parameter to work.